# Calculating likelihood for skewed normal distribution

Tags: probability, bayesian, likelihood, skew-normal-distribution

I would like to make a probabilistic estimate of a continuous parameter θ using Bayes' theorem. Initially, I assume that the true value of θ is equally likely to be anywhere in the interval [0,20].

Now I want to update this prior with additional/independent information (given by a skew-normal distribution with known *a*, *location* and *scale*). To do this, I of course need to know the likelihood that a given value of θ has within this PDF. If the PDF were normally distributed, calculating the likelihood would be possible by integrating the corresponding CDF up to the z-score. However, the PDF is asymmetric/right-skewed so the previous approach using the z-score doesn't work.

[image]

Now I am at a loss of what to do. How can I calculate the likelihood within a skew-normal PDF?

Comment: The likelihood for $\theta$ given an observation $x$ is proportional to the probability or density for $x$ given $\theta$.  You should not need to integrate that (though you may need to integrate the prior times the likelihood over $\theta$ to have a factor which turn your posterior into a probability distribution with total probability $1$)

Comment: *skew-normal distribution with known a, location and scale* is unclear. Which parameter is a? What is $\theta$? Please specify which of the skewnormal parameters are known, which are unknown.